# Configuring build so that App is launched, not acivity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-launcher

I am currently launching my app from Android Studio deploys, but then attempts to open the activity named `EditOrCreateEvent`, by showing:

[image]

even though the launcher is on the login activity:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".app.Session.LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Also, the app does not start up automatically, therefore I must navigate and find the app on my phone to open it.

Just a few days ago, upon running from Android Studio, the app would open on phone with no issues, the only change was switching to Gradle 1.5.

How can this be alleviated? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to change configuration of your app using below step:

**1.** Goto **Edit Configurations...** -> [image: Edit Configurations...]

**2.** Select **app** option and select **General** tab. There is **Launch option**. Then select **Default Activity** and save your app configuration.

[image: Edit Configurations...]

DONE.
I hope its helps you.